# How to solve $8x^2 = x \ln(x)$

Tags: logarithms

When does $8x^2$  outperform $x \ln(x)$ function.
I found such problem in O(n) computations and had not found answer swiftly

Comment: You can probably get it to $$8x=\ln x$$, no?

Comment: True, but that is the place where I have stopped.

Comment: $8x = ln(x) \implies e^{8x} = x \implies  1= xe^{-8x} \implies -8= -8xe^{-8x} \implies W(-8) = -8x \implies x = -W(-8)/8$

Comment: No real roots, which you would know if you just [plotted both functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%3DLog%5Bx%5D). They never intersect on a real line. So, in that sense $8x^2$ always 'outperforms' $x \ln x$

Comment: You're In My Eye, that is why I can not understand what is wrong with equation. Maybe, I just forgot real numbers and that is why it is a question for mathexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$8x^2=x\ln(x)$

$8x=\ln(x)$

$e^{8x}=x$

$xe^{-8x}=1$

$-8xe^{-8x}=-8$

$-8x=W(-8)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

---

According to WolframAlpha, $W(-8) \approx 1.199\ldots +
2.091\ldots i$